# ExtJS renderTo element not found

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have an MVC architecture, but when I try to make another TabPanel insite an existing one, I get this in the browser:

`el is null`

`el = el.dom || Ext.getDom(el);    ext-all-debug.js (line 12807)`

From what I understand, it seems that the new TabPanel can't find the needed div for it to render. Anyway, here is the controller:

```
Ext.define('FI.controller.MainController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
id: 'mainController',
views: ['MainTabPanel', 'UnitsTabPanel', 'SummariesTabPanel'],
mainTabPanel : {}, 
unitsTabPanel : {},
summariesTabPanel : {},
init: function(){
    console.log("main controller is init");
    console.log(this);

    this.control({
        'mainTabPanel':{
            afterrender: this.onCreate
        }
    });


    this.mainTabPanel = Ext.widget('mainTabPanel');
},

onCreate: function(){
    console.log("main tab panel is created");
    console.log(this);
    this.unitsTabPanel = Ext.widget('unitsTabPanel');
    this.summariesTabPanel = Ext.widget('summariesTabPanel');
}
});
```

This is the **MainTabPanel**:

```
Ext.define("FI.view.MainTabPanel", {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
renderTo:'container',
alias: 'widget.mainTabPanel',
enableTabScroll: true,
items:[{
        title:'Units',
        html: "<div id='units'></div>",
        closable: false
    },
    {title: 'Summaries',
        html: "<div id='summaries'></div>",
        closable:false
    }
]
});
```

And this is the **SummariesTabPanel**(the one with problems):

```
Ext.define("FI.view.SummariesTabPanel", {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
renderTo: 'summaries',
alias: 'widget.summariesTabPanel',
enableTabScroll: true
});
```

The problem is with the `SummariesTabPanel`. If I don't create it, the `UnitsTabPanel` gets rendered. For some reason, it can't find the `summaries` div.

Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Try to get the "summaries" div just after creating the maintabpanel, using `document.getElementById('summaries')`. What do you get (via `console.log()`)?

Comment: @PaoloStefan I get `null`. Why doesn't it get created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SummariesTabPanel renders to the "units" div according to your last snippet of code, is that correct? If not, replace `renderTo: 'units'` with `renderTo: 'summaries'`.

---

**Edit**

Since it was not the case, you may take a look ath this piece of Ext 4 Panel documentation (here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-html ) that says that the html content isn't added until the component is completely rendered. So, you have to wait for the [afterrender](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-event-afterrender) event of the tab (not the tabpanel, as you do now) before you can actually get the DOM element.

If you instantiate this Panel

```
{title: 'Summaries',
 html: "<div id='summaries'></div>",
 closable:false
}
```

and store the pointer to it into a separate variable, you could listen to its afterrender event and try again.

A workaround to this could be using an existing element of the page (that is, a static html fragment) instead of adding it via the Panel's `html` config option.

Comment: Sorry, It was a typo. I have corrected it. Not this was the issue, I just copied it here wrong :D. What else is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this that way? If you want to have a nested panels - just define them inside one another. Don't use `renderTo`

```
Ext.define("FI.view.SummariesTabPanel", {
  extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel', 
  alias: 'widget.summariesTabPanel'
});


Ext.define("FI.view.MainTabPanel", {
  extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
  alias: 'widget.mainTabPanel',
  enableTabScroll: true,
  items:[{
      xtype: 'summariesTabPanel'
      title:'Units',
      closable: false
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't know why I have made this so complicated. But still, it should work, right?

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't tried it. Just seems wrong on the very deep level to me :)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to render them inside one another? Thought it would be simple, but apparently, couldn't find any method/config option to do such.